# Can I add card on stripe using stripe public key with android SDK

Tags: java, android, kotlin, stripe-payments

I am unable to card on stripe using public key, I want add card on stripe for feature payment using PaymentMethodId. Is it possible?

It is working with stripe secret key, But I cant use secret key at App level.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can create a payment method from your Android app by calling [stripe.createPaymentMethod()](https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/payments-core/com.stripe.android/create-payment-method.html).

There's also an [example code](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/stripe/example/activity/PaymentMethodViewModel.kt#L21) that you find from the Stripe Android Github repo.